# Unitrends Work with LTO-6?

Tags: backup, lto

Has anyone been able to get a Unitrends appliance to work with an LTO-6 drive?

I checked to compatibility matrix and while it does have a vague list of supported products is vague... and seemingly outdated...

I contacted support and they referenced the matrix.  I have heard from an SE that anything that supports MTX commands should work.

Any experience?

Comment: I can't quite understand your question. The `mtx` command is not used for communicating with tape drives. Rather it is used to communicate with the robot, that moves the tapes between drives and library cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's about right. The interface to an LTO-1, LTO-4, LTO-6 doesn't really differ... The Unitrends software/appliance is likely Linux and it sees the same device regardless of LTO type. You should be fine as long as you adjust capacity to reflect the size of your LTO-6 cartridges.